# Swipe to call using sim on which call was receipt

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, dual-sim

In the call logs, when you swipe on a call you answered, it will dial from sim1 even if you answered it from sim2. How to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to System Settings.
2. Under that look for "SIM Management" or "Dual SIM Settings".
3. There, change the "Default Behavior" for dual-SIM to "Always Ask".

Comment: This partly answers my question, in my previous phone I could edit contacts and choose default sim.

Comment: another thing is that with this option I always need to choose, I want it to call using the sim from the call log, so if I received a call with sim 1 when I swipe in the call log, I call that number with sim 1 and visa versa

Comment: That's how it works. I'm sorry. Apparently you can also choose a default sim per activity, but that is what you don't want